# Regarding xml parsing in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am developing an application in which I am doing XML parsing. I found an error in the `[xmlparse parse]` method.

Error:

```
[NSCFString bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3df6310

2010-04-30 00:09:46.302 SPCiphone2[4234:1003] void SendDelegateMessage
    (NSInvocation*): delegate (<CFNotificationCenter 0x3d09670 [0x87dca0]>)
    failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode:
    kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
```

Code snippet:

```
responseOfWebResultData = [[NSMutableString alloc]
                           initWithData:responseData
                               encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"result: %@", responseOfWebResultData);

// starting the XML parsing
if (responseOfWebResultData) {
    @try {
        xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:responseOfWebResultData];
        [xmlParser setDelegate:self];
        [xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:YES];
        [xmlParser parse];
        [responseOfWebResultData release];
    }
    @catch (NSException *e) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please"
                                                        message:[e reason]
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be passing in a NSString* into initWithData:. You should do this:

```
xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:responseData];
```

The error says that you're sending the message `bytes` to an instance of NSCFString, which is a NSString*, even though you declared it as a NSMutableString*, because this is a dynamically typed language but the class types are not automatically converted if you try to cast it to something else.

Comment: @lucius,you means the XMLParser should want only byte code data right?

Comment: I think so. When the method name is "initWithData:" you should pass in a NSData instance and not a NSString.

Comment: ok great.If we comments
responseOfWebResultData = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; NSLog(@"result: %@", responseOfWebResultData); both lines so there not been aftecing to other code.